# Is it possible to look at a URL and determine if it's using Struts?

Tags: struts

**example:**

```
http://www.boston.com/travel?p1=Levelone_Nav_travel
```

will we be able to say if this website code is developed using Struts framework ? If so how, details please.

Comment: Of course not; it could be anything. What's more, since it's at least partially an Angular site, it could be using multiple technologies.

Comment: "here's a box. was this put together by robot or by human?"

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

The HTTP headers *sometimes* include relevant information, but not reliably.